# Java - Align JTextArea to the Right

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jtextarea

I it possible to align the text inside a JTextArea to the right (or change the text alignment in general)?

```
|Left         |
|  Centered   |
|        Right|    <- Like this
```

I've been searching for hours and it seems others have asked this question before but there are no good answers (that actually work).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for whole text alignment or only for specific text in the `JTextArea`?

Comment: I am looking for aligning the entire text horizontally.

Comment: Can you use `JEditorPane`?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` instead of `JTextArea`.

Please have a look at my another post [JEditorPane vertical aligment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613016/jeditorpane-vertical-aligment) for complete sample code.

For more info have a look at this thread [Vertical Alignment of Text in JEditorPane](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1352946?start=0&tstart=0)

Sample code:

```
JTextPane output = new JTextPane();

SimpleAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(attribs, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
output.setParagraphAttributes(attribs, true);
```

---

#### EDIT

You can try

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
jTextArea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Read more about [How to set the orientation of JTextArea from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320/how-to-set-the-orientation-of-jtextarea-from-right-to-left-inside-joptionpane)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **JTextPane**, It's better than **JTextArea** on this case:

try this code:

```
JTextPane textPane=new JTextPane();
StyledDocument style = textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet align= new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(align, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
style.setParagraphAttributes(0, style.getLength(), align, false);
```

modify this code If You want to make the text:

+in the **Right** :

```
StyleConstants.setAlignment(align, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

+in the **Center** :

```
StyleConstants.setAlignment(align, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

+in the **Left** :

```
StyleConstants.setAlignment(align, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

Take a look at this [Centering Text in a JTextArea or JTextPane - Horizontal Text Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213045/centering-text-in-a-jtextarea-or-jtextpane-horizontal-text-alignment)