# add JPanel to right or left into JPanel

Tags: java, swing

i work with java swing
 I've tried witj some layout but they didnt'work.
I have a mainPanel that contains some panel,or to the right or to the left
,One below other,obviously.

anyone knows how to do ?
thanks to all

[image]

Comment: grid or gridbag layout... grid: all cells have same dimension, one child in one cell, one child max per cell. gridbag: slightly more complex. Use grid, 2x2, with one panel at (1,0), the other at (0,1).

Comment: but the number of pane are undefined, they can be 14 or 100

Comment: Then create a gridlayout accordingly at the time you know the number of panes, what is the problem?

Comment: it's a chat app, I can't know the number of message :)

Comment: Hey, now you begin to give us some good information about your needs... The trick is that you also need some scrolling... Use a scrollpane with a panel that use a gridlayout, and change the gridlayout when you need, you can start with say 100 lines (don't worry if ending lines are unused, and when construct another gridlayout when it grows... But I think you need to create your own layout/component to handle these more properly...

Comment: can you help me?can you give me an example of code for my own layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's a chat app,

If you are just displaying text in the panel you might be able to use a JTextPane with right/left aligned text as shown here: [Java Swing JTextArea write both left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365522/java-swing-jtextarea-write-both-left-and-right/37367300#comment62262818_37367300)

Or you want can use a `GridBagLayout` with one component per column. You would then need to use:

1. the `fill` constraint on each component so that is fills the width available in the row.
2. then for each component you would use the `anchor` constraint so the component is either on the `LINE_START` or `LINE_END`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using a GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on each of these constraints.

Or, you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which also allows for vertical layout of panels. In this case the code would be something like:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.Y_AXIS);
rl.setFill(true);
setLayout( rl );

JPanel left = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );
left.add(new JLabel("left"));
add(left);

JPanel right = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
right.add(new JLabel("right"));
add(right);
```

So you just need to manage the alignment of FlowLayout of each panel.